# Added external library can't be seen - NetBeans

Tags: jdbc, netbeans, jar, driver, external

I downloaded [SocketTest](https://github.com/akshath/SocketTest) project and made some changes to read data from MS SQL database. Added external library:
[image: external library was added]

But I'm getting `java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found...` when I run the project.

I'm sure there is no mistake in my source code. Because I tested my class on alternate project. It's running smoothly. But I wonder why MS SQL library can't be seen even after I add that.

I also tried to use the newest version of MS SQL library but still no success.

I also tried to analyze  project.xml file. But I guess solution is not there.

Please help me to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution has been found. build.xml file has been cleared and copied from newly created NetBeans project.